# how to insert comma separated string values in table for different ids

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array:

```
Array
(
    [user_ids] => 2,4,3
)
```

I want to insert these values in table like this

```
id |user_id
1  | 2
1  | 4
1  | 3
```

I have done this:

```
 $ids = explode(',', $user_ids); // explode

explode result
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 4
    [2] => 3
)
```

then in loop:

```
foreach($ids as $uid){
INSERT INTO user_venue_status (venue_id,user_id,group_id,status) VALUES(".$id.",'".$uid."','".$gid."','".$status."')
}
```

It inserts the last value only in table.

Comment: foreach loop through each entry in the array, and do an insert for each

Comment: Explode your comma separated values and rest check the [above^ comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32629437/how-to-insert-comma-seprated-string-values-in-table-for-different-ids#comment53107996_32629437)

Comment: Post your entire code not the least of it as this seems to be worked over here

Comment: In your insert query you are using `$id` from where they coming?

Comment: Change `foreach ($ids as $uid)` to `foreach ($ids as $id => $uid)`

Answer (score 0):

In your code it didn't show $gid and $status Use below code for insert record:

```
foreach($ids as $id=>$uid){
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO user_venue_status (venue_id,user_id,group_id,status) VALUES(".$id.",'".$uid."','".$gid."','".$status."')");
}
```